# How to fail SSIS Execute Process Task on failure of SQL Server BCP IN to transfer record(S)?

Tags: sql-server-2008, batch-file, ssis, bcp, ssis-2008

I have a **SSIS Execute Process Task** which calls a ***.bat*** file which calls SQL Server **BCP IN** to move data from a file to SQL Server.

Now even if **BCP IN** fails to transfer some records (due to data type mismatch) Execute Process Task *does not* fail.
We want Execute process task to fail in this condition. How can this be done?

When we run **BCP IN** directly on command prompt we get below kind of messages for records which BCP IN fails to transfer.

> SQLState = 22001, NativeError = 0
>   Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]String data, right truncation

We tried to use %ERRORLEVEL% but it remains set to 0.

Comment: BCP sets DOS ERRORLEVEL unpon failure in most circumstances. See here for an example of how to identify and propagate this. http://bytes.com/topic/sql-server/answers/82815-bcp-within-batch-file

Comment: %ERRORLEVEL% is set if BCP command has some probelm (say wrong connection string) but it is not set when some records are not loaded.

Comment: This link https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.sqlserver.tools/qzpWuZzJnr4 says BCP v9.0 sets the errorlevel correctly but v8.0 does not. Do you know which version you have?

Comment: I am using version 10.50.2811.0

Comment: So just to clarify (perhaps you could add to the original question), a truncation error leaves ERRORLEVEL at 0 - is that correct? I'm sorry I can't help further. Looks like there is a workaround if you send the output to a loag and check the log afterwards though.